# SQL Server Add Column then Update Column Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a sql script that modifies multiple tables after importing them. In one table I don't have a 'RCVDDATE' column but I do in another related table. I'm adding the new table with this command:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST.CASES.ADDRESS
ADD RCVDDATE DATE;
```

And then I'm running this command to bring in the correct values:

```
UPDATE TEST.CASES.ADDRESS
SET RCVDDATE = c.RCVDDATE
FROM TEST.CASES.CALLS c
Where TEST.CASES.ADDRESS.CALL_NUMBER = c.CALL_NUMBER;
```

Individually they work fine. But when I execute them in a script it throws an error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'RCVDDATE'.
```

Am I having a problem with Intellisense or is it something else? If you have any suggestions on how I can get the script to run in SQL Server, please advise.

Comment: put a GO between the ALTER and the UPDATE

Comment: i think you are missing "INNER JOIN TEST.CASES.ADDRESS" Clause

Comment: Putting a 'GO' between the requests worked. Thanks. 
Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GO statement to separate your batches.  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017

SQL Server applications can send multiple Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server for execution as a batch. The statements in the batch are then compiled into a single execution plan. Programmers executing ad hoc statements in the SQL Server utilities, or building scripts of Transact-SQL statements to run through the SQL Server utilities, use GO to signal the end of a batch.